# XCode 13 build error - code object is not signed at all

Tags: ios, xcode

I am going through Apple's [SwiftUI tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui). It was building fine till yesterday, however it has started giving this error now:

```
SchemeBuildError: Failed to build the scheme "Landmarks"

Sign Landmarks.app:
/Users/narbhati/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Landmarks-ahmqfcjmbjxmvognxcpanhaiieam/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/Landmarks/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Landmarks.app: code object is not signed at all
In subcomponent: /Users/narbhati/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Landmarks-ahmqfcjmbjxmvognxcpanhaiieam/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/Landmarks/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Landmarks.app/Assets.car
Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Would you please try to remove all DerivedData and then try again?

Comment: Tried it. Still same issue.